# Splice in perl script

Tags: perl, splice

```
my @writers = qw( Horace Ovid Virgil Asimov Heinlein Dante );
my @contemporary = splice @writers, 3, 2;
print join(' ', @contemporary);
```

**output**

```
Asimov Heinlein
```

---

```
my @writers = qw( Horace Ovid Virgil Asimov Heinlein Dante );
splice @writers, 3, 2;
print join(' ', @writers); # Horace Ovid Virgil Dante
```

**output**

```
Horace Ovid Virgil Dante
```

What is the difference between these scripts. Why it showing different output?

Comment: Because in the first case you are printing the return value of `splice`, and in the second case you are seeing the effect `splice` has had on the array `@writers`. You have no reason to expect that the two should be the same, and you expectation is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here

```
 my @contemporary = splice @writers, 3, 2;
 print join(' ', @contemporary);
```

it returns the elements that has been removed

while here

```
splice @writers,3,2;
print join(' ', @writers)
```

it just print the elements of the array

and in a scalar context for example

```
 my $contemporary = splice @writers, 3, 2;
 print $contemporary;
```

it will print the last element that has been removed

from [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html)

> Removes the elements designated by OFFSET and LENGTH from an array, and replaces them with the elements of LIST, if any. **In list context, returns the elements removed from the array**. In scalar context, returns the last element removed, or undef if no elements are removed. The array grows or shrinks as necessary. If OFFSET is negative then it starts that far from the end of the array. If LENGTH is omitted, removes everything from OFFSET onward. If LENGTH is negative, removes the elements from OFFSET onward except for -LENGTH elements at the end of the array. If both OFFSET and LENGTH are omitted, removes everything. If OFFSET is past the end of the array, Perl issues a warning, and splices at the end of the array.

Comment: could you explain why it behave like that?

Comment: It behaves like that because the designers of the function thought that this would be the most useful behaviour. And I can't see why you would disagree. What would you expect to see?

Comment: @user3114045: That is an entirely different question and should be posted as such. (And you shouldn't attempt to answer it here Muhiwara.)

Comment: @Borodin : yes sure, i just didnt understand which operator he was talking about

Comment: @Mugiwara: Yours was a fair comment, but it would be good if you could learn to ignore or flag new questions that are asked in comments. As you can see, the comment you responded to has been deleted, presumably because it should have been a new question.

Comment: @Matteo: Although correct, editing a post to *add a single insignificant space* is ridiculous.

Comment: @Matteo: Your correction is fine: I added a space in the same place to clarify the question. But if a single space is *all* you have to change then please leave the post alone.